# Play an audio file and return back to the page

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, quicktime

in my iPhone app, I have an UIWebView with some simple HTML links to audio files.
When the user opens such an audio file, media player plays it an leaves my
UIWebView with this screen:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090622-rnx614kynh8faecjmuiyec159b.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090622-rnx614kynh8faecjmuiyec159b.jpg)

**How do I dismiss it after the audio file was played?** 
I've searched for UIWebView's delegates without finding something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike, I've found a solution: Create a HTML page and embed your audio file the follwing way:

```
<embed src=”http://www.mypage.com/test.wav”>
```

This gives you an embedded mini player.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't dismiss that properly, or at least I couldn't figure out how to do it.  So I just used the movie player for all my audio and video.  It's a little more complex but it is much more flexible.